# Cannot deploy ARM template with custom role - InsufficientPrivilegesForManagedServiceResource

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-resource-manager

I have a custom role with the following permissions:

```json
        "permissions": [
            {
                "actions": [
                    "Microsoft.Resources/deployments/read",
                    "Microsoft.Resources/deployments/write",
                    "Microsoft.Resources/deployments/cancel/action",
                    "Microsoft.Resources/deployments/operations/read",
                    "Microsoft.Resources/deploymentScripts/write",
                    "Microsoft.Resources/deployments/validate/action",
                    "Microsoft.ManagedServices/registrationDefinitions/write",
                    "Microsoft.ManagedServices/registrationAssignments/write",
                    "Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourceGroups/write"
                ],
                "notActions": [],
                "dataActions": [],
                "notDataActions": []
            }
        ]
```

I tried deploy an ARM template at subscription scope that creates:

- registrationDeployment
- registrationAssignment
- resourceGroup
- deployment with deploymentScript

But whenever I try to validate and create such template, I get such error:

```json
{
  "code": "InvalidTemplateDeployment",
  "details": [
    {
      "code": "InvalidManagedServicesTemplateDeployment",
      "message": "The managed services template deployment file contains invalid values. Please see details.",
      "details": [
        {
          "code": "InsufficientPrivilegesForManagedServiceResource",
          "message": "The requested user doesn't have sufficient privileges to perform the operation."
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "message": "The template deployment 'Microsoft.Template-<template-id>' is not valid according to the validation procedure. The tracking id is '<id>'. See inner errors for details."
}
```

Looks like I'm missing some permission, but I'm not sure which.

EDIT: Attaching template

```json
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-08-01/subscriptionDeploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        ...
    },
    "variables": {
        "mspRegistrationName": "[guid(parameters('mspOfferName'))]",
        "rgName": "[format('somedata-{0}', deployment().location)]",
        "mspAssignmentName": "[guid(parameters('mspOfferName'))]",
        "managedByTenantId": "<tenant-id>",
        "deploymentLocation": "[deployment().location]",
        "deploymentName": "[deployment().name]",
        "authorizations": [
            {
                "principalId": "<p-id>",
                "roleDefinitionId": "ed7f3fbd-7b88-4dd4-9017-9adb7ce333f8",
                "principalIdDisplayName": "perm1"
            },
            {
                "principalId": "<p-id>",
                "roleDefinitionId": "0ab0b1a8-8aac-4efd-b8c2-3ee1fb270be8",
                "principalIdDisplayName": "perm2"
            },
            {
                "principalId": "<p-id>",
                "roleDefinitionId": "641177b8-a67a-45b9-a033-47bc880bb21e",
                "principalIdDisplayName": "perm2"
            }
        ],
        "callbackBody": "<pretend-it's-valid>",
        "callbackUri": "<valid-uri>"
    },
    "functions": [],
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.ManagedServices/registrationDefinitions",
            "apiVersion": "2020-02-01-preview",
            "name": "[variables('mspRegistrationName')]",
            "properties": {
                "registrationDefinitionName": "[parameters('mspOfferName')]",
                "description": "[parameters('mspOfferDescription')]",
                "managedByTenantId": "[variables('managedByTenantId')]",
                "authorizations": "[variables('authorizations')]"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.ManagedServices/registrationAssignments",
            "apiVersion": "2020-02-01-preview",
            "name": "[variables('mspAssignmentName')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.ManagedServices/registrationDefinitions/', variables('mspRegistrationName'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "registrationDefinitionId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.ManagedServices/registrationDefinitions/', variables('mspRegistrationName'))]"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups",
            "apiVersion": "2019-10-01",
            "name": "[variables('rgName')]",
            "location": "[variables('deploymentLocation')]",
            "tags": {
                "note": "Created only to run a deployment script"
            },
            "properties": {},
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.ManagedServices/registrationDefinitions/', variables('mspRegistrationName'))]",
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.ManagedServices/registrationAssignments/', variables('mspRegistrationName'))]"
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
            "apiVersion": "2019-10-01",
            "name": "someCallback",
            "resourceGroup": "[variables('rgName')]",
            "properties": {
                "expressionEvaluationOptions": {
                    "scope": "outer"
                },
                "mode": "Incremental",
                "parameters": {},
                "template": {
                    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
                    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
                    "parameters": {},
                    "functions": [],
                    "resources": [
                        {
                            "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deploymentScripts",
                            "apiVersion": "2020-10-01",
                            "name": "[format('someCallback-{0}', variables('deploymentName'))]",
                            "location": "[variables('deploymentLocation')]",
                            "kind": "AzurePowerShell",
                            "properties": {
                                "forceUpdateTag": "1",
                                "azPowerShellVersion": "6.6",
                                "scriptContent": "[format('Invoke-WebRequest -ContentType application/json -Method POST -Body (@{0}|ConvertTo-Json) -Uri {1}', variables('callbackBody'), variables('callbackUri'))]",
                                "supportingScriptUris": [],
                                "timeout": "PT3M",
                                "cleanupPreference": "Always",
                                "retentionInterval": "PT1H"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "dependsOn": [
                "[subscriptionResourceId('Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups', variables('rgName'))]"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "outputs": {
        ...
    }
}
```

EDIT: Since I want to onboard user into my tenant using Azure Lighthouse, I add more permissions to the user that is running the template. Yet still it did not work.
New Permissions:

```json
        "permissions": [
            {
                "actions": [
                    "Microsoft.Resources/deployments/read",
                    "Microsoft.Resources/deployments/write",
                    "Microsoft.Resources/deployments/delete",
                    "Microsoft.Resources/deployments/cancel/action",
                    "Microsoft.Resources/deployments/validate/action",
                    "Microsoft.Resources/deployments/operations/read",
                    "Microsoft.Resources/deployments/operationstatuses/read",
                    "Microsoft.Resources/deploymentScripts/read",
                    "Microsoft.Resources/deploymentScripts/write",
                    "Microsoft.Resources/deploymentScripts/delete",
                    "Microsoft.Resources/deploymentScripts/logs/read",
                    "Microsoft.ManagedServices/registrationDefinitions/write",
                    "Microsoft.ManagedServices/registrationAssignments/write",
                    "Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourceGroups/write",
                    "Microsoft.Resources/deployments/whatIf/action",
                    "Microsoft.Resources/deployments/exportTemplate/action",
                    "Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourcegroups/deployments/read",
                    "Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourcegroups/deployments/write",
                    "Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourcegroups/deployments/operations/read",
                    "Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourcegroups/deployments/operationstatuses/read",
                    "Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/assign/action",
                    "Microsoft.ManagedServices/register/action",
                    "Microsoft.ManagedServices/unregister/action",
                    "Microsoft.ManagedServices/marketplaceRegistrationDefinitions/read",
                    "Microsoft.ManagedServices/operations/read",
                    "Microsoft.ManagedServices/registrationAssignments/read",
                    "Microsoft.ManagedServices/registrationAssignments/delete",
                    "Microsoft.ManagedServices/registrationDefinitions/read",
                    "Microsoft.ManagedServices/registrationDefinitions/delete",
                    "Microsoft.ManagedServices/operationStatuses/read",
                    "Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/register/action",
                    "Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/operations/read",
                    "Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/identities/read",
                    "Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/delete",
                    "Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/listAssociatedResources/action",
                    "Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/read",
                    "Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/write"
                ],
                "notActions": [],
                "dataActions": [],
                "notDataActions": []
            }
        ]
```

Comment: What permissions do you have on the subscription? Try having Global Admin Role or Owner role

Comment: Please edit your question and include the template you are trying to deploy.

Comment: @GauravMantri, I added the template.

Comment: @SA, the user has only this one role I created. You can see the permission in the question body.

Comment: Check this discussion it might help you : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/250370/user-doesn39t-have-permission-to-create-deployment.html

Comment: Also **Connect-AzAccount** if you have only **connect-azureAD**

Comment: It still did not work. Since I want to deploy an ARM template that onboards the subscription into another tenants using Azure Lighthouse, I added more permissions. Unfortunately, it still did not work.